# How to convert this sed command to Python script?

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have one old shell script which include sed command as below.
The source data($Tmp) is a HTML table.

```
sed '/<table border/,/table>/d' $Tmp > $Out
```

Can someone help me to convert this command to Python script?
I really can't figure out how to do that with regular expression. 
Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script copys all lines from the input file to the output file, unless it finds a line containing `<table border`, then it deletes all lines until it finds `/table>` and continues writing all further lines.

So one possibility would be:

```
with open('in') as inf, open('out', 'w') as outf:
    while True:
        line = inf.readline()
        if '<table border' in line:
            while True:
                line = inf.readline()
                if not line or '/table>' in line:
                    line = inf.readline()
                    break
        if not line:
            break
        outf.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation.

Briefly, it opens the file, iterates line by line and prints each line to the output. If it matches `"<table border"`, delete flag set to True and following lines aren't printed to the output until it matches `"table>"`.

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
delete = False
for line in f:
    if delete == False:
        if "<table border" in line:
            delete = True

    if delete == False:
        print line,

    if delete == True:
        if "table>" in line:
            delete = False
```

Comment: using `re` to search for a plain string within an other string is a bit overkill, a simple `in` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '<table border' in line:
            for line in f:
                if 'table>' in line:
                    break
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```